# Metadata file .dll could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, class, namespaces, n-tier-architecture

My project can't find the namespaces. Does someone know what the problem is?

I have tried a lot of option to fix the problem. But not one of them works.

I have tried: clean solution, build solution, refactor and

Right click on the solution and click Properties.

Click Configuration on the left.

Make sure the check box under Build for the project it can't find is checked.

If it is already checked, uncheck, hit apply and check the boxes again.

Here is a screenshot of my code. [screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIq4Q.png)

```
    <Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

      <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />

      <PropertyGroup>

        <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
        <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
        <ProjectGuid>{DD7D144A-06C0-482A-9142-3CD989CCC7A4}</ProjectGuid>
        <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
        <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
        <RootNamespace>NTier.BLL</RootNamespace>
        <AssemblyName>NTier.BLL</AssemblyName>
        <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6.1</TargetFrameworkVersion>
        <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">

        <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
        <DebugType>full</DebugType>
        <Optimize>false</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">

        <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
        <Optimize>true</Optimize>
        <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
        <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
        <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
        <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="System" />
        <Reference Include="System.Core" />
        <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq" />
        <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions" />
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
        <Reference Include="System.Data" />
        <Reference Include="System.Net.Http" />
        <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="Admin\AdminLogic.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Customer\CustomerLogic.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Admin\IAdminLogic.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Customer\ICustomerLogic.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Customer\INotRegularCustomerLogic.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Customer\IRegularCustomerLogic.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Customer\NotRegularCustomerLogic.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Customer\RegularCustomerLogic.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Order\IOrderLogic.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Order\OrderLogic.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Product\IProductLogic.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Review\IReviewLogic.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Product\ProductLogic.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
        <Compile Include="Review\ReviewLogic.cs" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\NTier.DAL\NTier.DAL.csproj">

          <Project>{a42bdcd5-0ec1-4d2a-b96a-92e39138e9cb}</Project>
          <Name>NTier.DAL</Name>
        </ProjectReference>
        <ProjectReference Include="..\NTier.Domain\NTier.Domain.csproj">
          <Project>{70a4d682-67bb-456b-a21d-f343b43fe1b6}</Project>
          <Name>NTier.Domain</Name>
        </ProjectReference>
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <WCFMetadata Include="Connected Services\" />
      </ItemGroup>
      <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
    </Project>
```

Here is the code that you asked for. Hopefully you can help with my problem.

Comment: Where you have defined the class "Product", probably in the referenced project? Could you, please, share the .csproj file?

Comment: Look at the new post. I can't share the code in this comment.

Comment: Please, edit your question and add the .csproj file content

Comment: I need to see the project .csproj file, not the class Product

Comment: i can't even get in my .csproj file ....

Comment: close visual studio, then open the csproj file with notepad

Comment: Can you build NTier.DAL and NTier.Domain projects?

Comment: As @HarutyunImirzyan suggested right click and try building dal and domain projects. Then build bll project. Edit question and post any error you get. Without exact error message, it is hard to guess what it cannot find.

Comment: re-attach your code screenshot for other people references, please :) (i've had that opened some time ago and i was able to analyze your problem now, sorry i got quite busy few hours ago and could not do that when i've opened that topic, but i hope my answer helps you)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is conflict between your namespace in `ProductLogic` class and the name of Product class from `NTier.Domain` namespace. It has not much to do with the project reference. In this case VS has priority over current namespace, not class from other namespace.
You need to use `NTier.Domain.Product` each time for each `Product` class usage in that case or change your `NTier.BLL.Product` Namespace to something else; for instance `NTier.BLL.ProductLogic`

It also doesn't seem true you "can't" use `Ntier.Domain` namespace (referring to the screenshot attached and comment in there): it's grayed out because it is not used at all (as VS doesn't connect any of Product strings used in code to the class you would like it to do, but to current namespace, so none of classes from `Ntier.Domain` is used and VS says you "you can remove that reference, it's not used"), to check that:
if you put our mouse over Product reference you should see something like that:

[image]

which informs you that VS is not seeing a class there, but your current namespace